# DataGridView styling the Scrollbars

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Im using `WinForms` and the `DataGridView`.

I have styled the application to utilize the `FlatAppearance` and all looks OK.

The only issue I have is trying to Style the `Scrollbars` to be a single Flat color and no visual style.

Is there some way to override this default behavior ?

Also, can this also be done for DataGridViews header row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your second question. You can use this code to customize the Headers font and the color:

```
void DataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            Brush gradientBrush;
            var grd = (DataGridView)sender;

            //header
            if (e.RowIndex == -1)
            {
                gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(...gradientParams..);
                e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(...FontParams...);

            }
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(gradientBrush, e.CellBounds);
        gradientBrush.Dispose();

        // paint rest of cell
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Border | DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
        e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Im not sure which rectangle to put in, I currently have this
                gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(dataGridView1.DisplayRectangle, Color.Black, Color.Red, 6.5f);
                e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(this.Font ,FontStyle.Italic);
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black;

Comment: the font changed but not the Cell Header backcolor, its still the default 3D style

Comment: Ops sorry. I forgot the lasts lines of the code because I removed a lot of them that were about other topics.